# Use custom command to open files

Tags: command-line, nautilus, scripts, gedit

`gedit` application is set as default application for text files. Supposing I have a script with execution rights in `/usr/bin`, how can I set that script to be run when I open a text file using Nautilus or `xdg-open`?

`/usr/bin/foo`:

```
echo "Works!"
gedit $*
```

If I do `foo my_text_file`, then `Works!` message will appear and `gedit` will run. How can I set this `foo` script to be run as default application?

Comment: @KingShimkus When I click a text file in Nautilus window I want to the following command to be run: `foo /home/whoami/.../clicked_text_file`. How can I do this?

Comment: I just edited my answer with the proper way (in case you missed it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The clean way would be to create a `.desktop` file for your script and then make it the default text editor.

1. Create a file called `/usr/share/applications/foo.desktop` with the following contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=foo
   Exec=/usr/bin/foo.sh %U
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   MimeType=text/plain;
   ```
2. Make it the default program for the `text/plain` mimetype:

   ```
   xdg-mime default foo.desktop "text/plain"
   ```

---

As a dirty hack you could also simply call your script `gedit`:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/gedit /usr/bin/gedit.orig
sudo mv /path/to/yourscript.sh /usr/bin/gedit
```

Then make your script call the original:

```
echo "Works!"
/usr/bin/gedit.original "$@"
```